# How to Make Jquery .load() function work once and Ajax request once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When the page is loaded contents from the PHP file has to load, for that i am using JQuery .load() function, content is successfully loading but it keep loading, i can see it from chrome Developer tools. I have to load content only once.

```
var userName =$('#dT').data('uname');
$('#dT').load('load_table.php', {userName:userName});
```

So i tried another Jquery ajax method that also same as loads the contents continuously..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadTable(){            
        var userName =$('#dT').data('uname');
        $.ajax({
                url:'load_table.php',
                data:{'userName':userName},
                success: function(results){
                    $('#dT').html(results); 
                    setTimeout(loadTable,5000);     
                }           
            });
        }
          loadTable();
        });
```

Above setTimeout function not working, any way to load content from PHP file only once?

Comment: You are calling loadTable inside of it... So every 5 seconds it makes an Ajax call

Comment: I have called that outside of loadTable function but inside the $(document).ready(), and it is not makes ajax call every 5 seconds. without any timeout keep calling.

Comment: setTimeout(loadTable,5000);  <-- calls the Ajax call every 5 seconds... (I also have no idea what your problem actually is) So in the network panel is the Ajax call actually successful or is it returning an error.

Comment: Before reach 5 seconds it's keep calling.. that's not working..

Comment: `success : function () { ... }, error : function() { console.error(arguments); }`

Comment: In your first, basic `.load()` version, what do you mean "content keeps loading"?  What do you see in Dev tools?  And how/when is the .load() called?

Comment: when the page is loaded <div id="dT" class="sad" data-uname="NAME"></div> i am loading a table to div from a php file, in that table there is a button called delete, delete button didn't work then i found out, it is keep loading, i have to load the table from PHP file only once.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your first load attempt you are loading the html with the exact same code, so it will keep on loading itself infinity.

Doing it with ajax is much better, however if I were you I would move the settimeout outside the function itself. Currently it will only trigger if the initial call was successful, you want it to run every 5 seconds I am guessing. So where you call it the first time at the bottom, instead of just

```
loadTable();
```

You have:

```
setTimeout(loadTable,5000);
```

Now you do not need to do the settimeout in the success function.

Comment: How to load only once after page is loaded, just once without any timeout?

Comment: Simply remove the timeout, then it will only call once the page has loaded and never again.